# main method executes without executing static block

Tags: java

I have a class like this-

```
class A {
    static {
        A obj = new A();
    }
    int x = 0;

    public A() {}

    public static int square(int x) {
        return x * x;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //A obj = new A();
        System.out.println("Hello World!" + square(4));
    }
}
```

This code give `StackOverFlowException` if we create a new object in `main` method, as code stuck in infinite loop. Same should be true for static block. But given code compiles and run fine. Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: Why would it even if you create a new object ?

Comment: creating a new object won't cause a `StackOverFlowException` here. That must've been caused by something else.

Comment: The static block will only get executed once, when the class is loaded by the ClassLoader.

Comment: @jgitter Also,because constructor is empty and does not create further objects

Comment: @KumarAbhinav it doesn't matter.  The static block only gets executed once regardless of what the constructor does at the time of instantiation.

Comment: @jgitter If the constructor calls the creation of a new Object,then StackOverFlowException will occur even if static initialzer is called only once .
static {
        A obj = new A();
    }
    int x = 0;

    public A() {new A();}

Comment: @KumarAbhinav I'm not disagreeing with you, I don't need you to correct me.  The answer has been established.

Comment: As written right now, there is no way this would cause a StacOverFlowException. You create a single `A` instance (statically), then print "Hello World" and the square of 4. Did you copy your code wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Moving  `A obj = new A();` inside the static block will cause the `A` Object to be created only once.This is because your default constructor is empty and it wont invoke creation of other Objects.
If your constructor contains a call to create another Object,it will recursively call the creating of further Objects

**First Case :-**

```
static {
        A obj = new A();
    }
    int x = 0;

    public A() {}  ///// gets executed due to static initalizer and stops there.
```

**Second Case :-**

```
public A() {

  A obj = new A();
}  ///// recursively calls Objects resulting in `StackOverFlowException`
```

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, you had wrote your program this way:

```
public A() 
{
    A obj = new A();
}
```

and you have not correctly copied your code to this question.

Anyway, the above piece of code creates a new instance in the constructor which leads to a chain of never ending calls which ultimately fill up stack space available and results in a stack overflow exception. This has nothing to do with the static block.